# How did the aliens destroy Cheyenne Mountain?

Tags: independence-day

In Independence Day, how did the aliens destroy one of the toughest nuclear bunkers in the world?

I believe they only attacked with their planes, not the City Destroyers, which wouldn't be enough firepower to get to the bunker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [official novelisation](https://independenceday.fandom.com/wiki/Independence_Day_(novel)) (co-authored by the film's scriptwriter), a significant number of alien planes took turns "*firing continuously*" on the mountain, eventually exposing the missile bunker and command centre inside.

> The aide explained more fully. “I have it from pilots out of Peterson.
> They were in the sky when alien attack planes massed over NORAD and
> began firing continuously for several minutes. Eventually, the entire
> complex was exposed and destroyed.